# Trouble instantiating class in a subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have a module in a subdirectory and when I try to import it, I get a `NameError: name`foo`is not defined`. When I put the class code directly into the `__main__.py` file it works fine. `__init__.py` files are empty.

I've tried the following all with other errors:

```
MyProject/
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── foo/
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

**bar.py**

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        print( 'am here' )
        pass
```

**__main__.py**

```
from MyProject import foo
#from MyProject import bar # errors with cannot import bar from MyProject
#from foo import bar # errors with No module named foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Bar()
```

Is there perhaps a better way to organise this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bar` class is in the file `bar.py`, so I think you'd need to do

```
from MyProject.foo import bar
w = bar.Bar()
```

or

```
from MyProject.foo.bar import Bar
w = Bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know from what direcrory file will be runed then use `.` to show where package is

```
from .foo.bar import Bar
```

or

```
from .foo import bar
w = bar.Bar()
```

or

```
import .foo
w = foo.bar.Bar()
```

`.` before package name means that package lockated in same directory with current file

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your `foo/__init__.py`, but you could fix the situation by adding something like this to it:

```
from .bar import Bar
```

That adds `Bar` to the namespace of `foo` and causes Python to find `Bar` when you just import `foo`.

However, you would probably do well to look at a few standard examples for writing a package. For one, you probably shouldn't name your project `MyProject`, as that name signals it's a class (with TitleCase). Naming it 'project' further confuses the issue, as it appears you're writing a *package*, so `my_package` sounds about right.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just did that naming for this example, but yeah that makes sense. Also the init files are empty atm